# Working with beta reduce

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I brought the [Haskell book](http://haskellbook.com/) and struggle with beta reduce.

I do understand the concept but do not know, how to use it, when I have a lambda in front of me.
For example:

```
(λ a b c . c b a) z z (λ w v . w)
```

How to reduce it?

Comment: Which Haskell book did you buy? Please specify...

Comment: The best one http://haskellbook.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all:

```
(λ a b c . c b a) z z (λ w v . w)
```

is short for:

```
(λ a . (λ b . (λ c . c b a) ) ) z z (λ w . (λ v . w) )
```

Well given you apply beta-reduction on:

```
(λ a b c . c b a) z z (λ w v . w)
```

(boldface added for the "active" variable so to speak, and italics for its replacement)

you thus replace **`a`** with the oparand *`z`* so, now the result is:

```
(λ b c . c b z) z (λ w v . w)
```

So we replaced `a` by `z` in the **scope of the lambda expression**, next we perform an additional reduction:

```
(λ b c . c b z) z (λ w v . w)
```

to:

```
(λ c . c z z) (λ w v . w)
```

Now you can also use beta-reduction to **inject functions** as is demonstrated here:

```
(λ c . c z z) (λ w v . w)
```

Into:

```
((λ w v . w) z z)
```

So we have not ended yet. Because again there is a lambda expression in the head:

```
(λ w v . w) z z
```

into:

```
(λ v . z) z
```

and finally the book demonstrates that a variable in the head does not need a variable in the body, so the last beta-reduction has no effect **on the body** (but it removes the last lambda-expression):

```
(λ v . z) z
```

into:

```
(z)
```

or:

```
z
```

Beta reduction is more or less what is behind every functional programming language: Haskell calls the beta-reduction repeatedly - if needed, since it is lazy - until the resulting value is derived.

Comment: @zero_coding: don't know one immediately: I learned beta-reductions in the *Automata and Computability* course, but the coursetext is in Dutch :(

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer.

Comment: @zero_coding Types and Programming Languages by Benjamin Pierce is one very popular introductory text on this topic.